# Why H2 is not storing BLOBs as separate files?

Tags: spring, jpa, h2

I am using H2 v1.4 embedded - MVStore, Spring and JPA

Now H2 documentation says

> By default, this database stores large LOB (CLOB and BLOB) objects separate from the main table data. Small LOB objects are stored in-place,

which is something I would expect - however, for whatever reasons, H2 is still pushing large BLOB content to the main db file. I have tried setting  `MAX_LENGTH_INPLACE_LOB` to values like 1 or even 0 however that didnt do any difference. How can I force H2 to start saving blobs as separate files?

Field defined in entity

```
@Lob
private Blob source;
```

I have also tried using `byte[]` with `@Column(definition="BLOB")` but the result was exactly the same

Blob creation (

```
 Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            return Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(inputStream, inputStream.available());
```

Save/Read works just fine - the only problem is that I would rather have blobs as separate files

Answer (score 1):

Documentation doesn't talk about separate **files** and you can't force H2 to use them.

Every table has a primary index where all its data is stored. When database reads a row, it reads the whole row with all its columns. Large values may create a noticeable overhead. But LOB values (excluding small values not exceeding `MAX_LENGTH_INPLACE_LOB`) are stored separately and aren't accessed when row is read, so they don't create that overhead. LOB object is only read when an application reads its content.

*Some queries don't use the primary index. For example, if you have an index on `(A, B)` columns query `SELECT B FROM tableName WHERE A = ?` will use only that index. `SELECT B, C … WHERE A = ?` will use that index and the primary index. But it isn't directly related with your question.*

Comment: Actually, PageStore was keeping blobs as separate files in `dbname.lobs.db/* ` (just as eg Mysql does). I have no idea why this has been changed. Another thing - since all tables are stored in single file - how is that *separate storage* separate? It's not to me. it it just that data can be read in "2 phases" and nothing else?

Comment: I think you're talking about archaic versions of H2 where LOB storage was entirely different. All data is stored in the main file, but in the different places of the file. Table scan operation doesn't need to read unrelated data of other tables from the file system and doesn't need to read values of LOBs, unlike values of other data types.